# A basic question in linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following claim:
Let $V$ be a vector space and let $A,B\subseteq V$ be two independent sets with $|A|<|B|<\infty $. Then there exists $b\in B$ such that $A\cup \{b\}$ is independent.

Can anyone prove this claim *without* using matrices?

Comment: Something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma) might help.

Comment: The basic result here is the (Steinitz) *Exchange Lemma*. A  web search should turn up much, including that it generalizes from *linear* dependence to  *abstract dependence relations* (e.g. *algebraic* dependence), cf. *matroid* theory.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\,|A|<|B|\,\,$ and both are lin. independent set, we get that $$\dim \operatorname{Span}(A)<\dim\operatorname{Span}(B)\,\,(**)$$

Now, we know that for any vector $$\,v\in V\,\,,\,v\in\operatorname{Span}(A)\Longleftrightarrow A\cup\{v\}\,\text{is linearly dependent}$$

So if $$\forall b\in B\,,\,A\cup\{b\}\,\text{is linearly dependent, then} \forall b\in B\,,\,b\in\operatorname{Span}(A)$$ which contradicts (**) above

Comment: The claim in the question is used to prove the fact that the dimension of a space is well defined.... Using it to prove the claim gives a circular argument.

Comment: Perhaps for you, @Shay. I didn't studied and learnt about dimension by means of this question or something like this, though perhaps The Replacement Theorem could be applied to both.

Answer (score 1):

Assume not:

Then if $|A| = n$, $|B| \geq n+1$, choose $n+1$ (linearly independent) elements $b_1, b_2, ..., b_{n+1}$ elements of $B$. If all $n+1$ elements are dependent with $A$, then the $n$ elements spanning $A$ span a $(n+1)$-dimensional space. Contradiction.

Comment: How do you prove that n elements can not span n+1 independent element? This is the essence of the question... Also note that the fact we need to prove in this question is used to define the concept of dimension...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can reduce to the case in which $|A| = |B|-1$, and then to the case $|A|=1$ and $|B|=2$. You can just add a vector $b$ to $A$ so that $\operatorname{span}\{A,b\}$ is a base for $B$.